# Criação de tabelas flutter gerando erro no such table

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou com um problema onde não estou conseguindo criar mais de uma tabela no sqlite com fluuter. Ao tentar criar uma tabela caso o banco já tenha sido criado gera o erro `no such table`

Estou criando da seguinte forma:

```
static Future<Database> database() async {
  final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
  final sql = '''CREATE TABLE cartoes(
    id INTEGER,
    instituiBanc int NOT NULL,
    bandeira int NOT NULL,
    isDebito INTEGER,
    vencimento TEXT,
    saldoDisponivel REAL,
    limite REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
  )''';

  return openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'table.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
    return db.execute(sql);
    },
    version: 1,
  );
}

static Future<Database> database() async {
final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
final sql = '''CREATE TABLE categoria(
  id INTEGER,
  descricao TEXT NOT NULL,
  isReceita INTEGER ,
  PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
)''';

return openDatabase(
  path.join(dbPath, 'table.db'),
  onCreate: (db, version) {
    return db.execute(sql);
  },
  version: 1,
);
}
```

Se ele entrar no banco e entrar o mesmo já criado, ele não deveria criar apenas a tabela faltante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você deve criar todas as tabelas que precisa ao criar o Banco de Dados.
Cada nova tabela adicionada depois deve ser adicionada junto com o incremento da versão "*version*".

Para o seu caso, faça da seguinte forma, que assim deve funcionar:

```
static Future<Database> database() async {
  final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();

  final sqlCartoes = '''CREATE TABLE cartoes(
    id INTEGER,
    instituiBanc int NOT NULL,
    bandeira int NOT NULL,
    isDebito INTEGER,
    vencimento TEXT,
    saldoDisponivel REAL,
    limite REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
  )''';
  
  final sqlCategoria = '''CREATE TABLE categoria(
    id INTEGER,
    descricao TEXT NOT NULL,
    isReceita INTEGER ,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
  )''';

  return openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'table.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) async {
      await db.execute(sqlCartoes);
      await db.execute(sqlCategoria);
    },
    version: 1,
  );
}
```

Se quiser mais alguns exemplos, você pode ver na própria página do package [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite).